# Автотест(js+Playwright)

Tags: javascript, тестирование, автоматизация, playwright

Есть задание: зайти на сайт, ввести три строки в поле ввода, проверить, что строки именно три.
Почему автотест не считает позиции списка? Он не создает список или не вдит селекторы списка?
Как вообще посмотреть ход выполнения автотеста в браузере?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qNoz.png)

Я пробовала менять селектор, но это не помогло

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.